# How to unset data from json file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

how do i delete my data in json file, heres my json file data, i want to clear the data of my json file.

```
 {"name":null,"timestart":"00:00","timeend":"00:00","day":null},
 {"name":"henrix","timestart":"7:00","timeend":"7:30","day":"tuesday"}]
```

i tried this code but its not delete the data, its saving another data but its null

```
<?php 

$file = 'timetable.json';
$json_file  = file_get_contents($file);
$file_content = json_decode($json_file);

foreach ($file_content as $key => $value) {

$name = $file_content[$key]->name;
$timestart = date("H:i", strtotime($file_content[$key]->timestart));
$timeend = date("H:i", strtotime($file_content[$key]->timeend));
$day = $file_content[$key]->day;
$reservations[] = array(
  "name" => $name,
  'timestart'=> $timestart,
  'timeend'=> $timeend,
  'day'=> $day
  );
 }

  $reservations[] = array(
  "name" => null,
  'timestart'=> null,
  'timeend'=> null,
  'day'=> null
  );

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($reservations));

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'henriks.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit();

?>
```

Comment: `code`<?php 

$file = 'timetable.json';
$json_file  = file_get_contents($file);
$file_content = json_decode($json_file);

  foreach ($file_content as $key => $value) {
 unset($file_content[$key]);
    
  }

   $reservations[] = array(
      "name" => null,
      'timestart'=> null,
      'timeend'=> null,
      'day'=> null
      );

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($reservations));

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'henriks.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit();

?>

Answer (score 0):

can't you just output an empty Json string in it ?

```
file_put_contents('yourFile.json', json_encode([] /* empty array */))
```

Comment: <?php 

$file = 'timetable.json';
$json_file  = file_get_contents($file);
$file_content = json_decode($json_file);

  foreach ($file_content as $key => $value) {
 unset($file_content[$key]);
    
  }

   $reservations[] = array(
      "name" => null,
      'timestart'=> null,
      'timeend'=> null,
      'day'=> null
      );

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($reservations));

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'henriks.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit();

?>

Answer (score 0):

use delete: `delete $reservations[].name`

Comment: its working sorry, i just deleted some codes and adding some.

Answer (score 0):

Well it makes sense since you're json_encoding() an array which contains data ( `$reservations`), albeit with null values.

Assuming you want an empty array, this should do it.

```
file_put_contents('timetable.json', "[]");
```

Comment: its working sorry, i just deleted some codes and adding some.